# Read dataset in R in which comma is used for field separator and decimal point

Tags: r, matrix, load, dataset

How could you read this dataset in `R`, the problem is 
that the numbers are *floats* and are like `4,000000059604644E+16`
and they are separated by a `,`

```
4,000000059604644E-16 ,  7,999997138977056E-16,   9,000002145767216E-16
4,999999403953552E-16 ,  6,99999988079071E-16 ,   0,099999904632568E-16
9,999997615814208E-16 ,  4,30000066757202E-16 ,   3,630000114440918E-16
0,69999933242798E-16  ,  0,099999904632568E-16,  55,657576767799999E-16 
3,999999761581424E-16,   1,9900000095367432E-16,  0,199999809265136E-16
```

How would you load this kinf of dataset in R so it has 3 columns.

If I do

```
dataset <- read.csv("C:\\data.txt",header=T,row.names=NULL)
```

it would return 6 columns instead 3...

Comment: Don't forget to tell the Excel monkey who sent you this not to use the same separator as their decimal point marker when saving a CSV file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be best to transform that input data to use decimal points, rather than commas, in the floating point numbers. One way you could do this is to use sed (it looks like you are using Windows, so you would likely need to sed to use this approach):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\)/\1.\2/g' data.txt  > data2.txt
```

File `data2` looks like this:

```
4.000000059604644E-16 ,  7.999997138977056E-16,   9.000002145767216E-16
4.999999403953552E-16 ,  6.99999988079071E-16 ,   0.099999904632568E-16
9.999997615814208E-16 ,  4.30000066757202E-16 ,   3.630000114440918E-16
0.69999933242798E-16  ,  0.099999904632568E-16,  55.657576767799999E-16 
3.999999761581424E-16,   1.9900000095367432E-16,  0.199999809265136E-16
```

Then in R:

```
dataset <- read.csv("data2.txt",row.names=NULL)
```

Comment: You could, of course, use any sufficiently powerful search and replace tool to do the transformation to the data.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an all R solution that uses three `read.table` calls. The first `read.table` statement reads each data row as 6 fields; the second `read.table` statement puts the fields back together properly and reads them and the third grabs the names from the header.

```
fn <- "data.txt"

# create a test file

Lines <- "A , B , C
4,000000059604644E-16 ,  7,999997138977056E-16,   9,000002145767216E-16
4,999999403953552E-16 ,  6,99999988079071E-16 ,   0,099999904632568E-16
9,999997615814208E-16 ,  4,30000066757202E-16 ,   3,630000114440918E-16
0,69999933242798E-16  ,  0,099999904632568E-16,  55,657576767799999E-16 
3,999999761581424E-16,   1,9900000095367432E-16,  0,199999809265136E-16"
cat(Lines, "\n", file = fn)

# now read it back in

DF0 <- read.table(fn, skip = 1, sep = ",", colClasses = "character")
DF <- read.table(
   file = textConnection(do.call("sprintf", c("%s.%s %s.%s %s.%s", DF0))), 
   col.names = names(read.csv(fn, nrow = 0))
)
```

which gives:

```
> DF
             A            B            C
1 4.000000e-16 7.999997e-16 9.000002e-16
2 4.999999e-16 7.000000e-16 9.999990e-18
3 9.999998e-16 4.300001e-16 3.630000e-16
4 6.999993e-17 9.999990e-18 5.565758e-15
5 4.000000e-16 1.990000e-16 1.999998e-17
```

*Note:* The `read.csv` statement in the question implies that there is a header but the sample data does not show one.  I assumed that there is a header but if not then remove the `skip=` and `col.names=` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it should work:

```
x <- matrix(scan("c:/data.txt", what=character(), sep=","), byrow=TRUE, ncol=6)
y <- t(apply(x, 1, function(a) { left <- seq(1, length(a), by=2)
                               as.numeric(paste(a[left], a[left+1], sep="."))
                             } ))
```